# Drag and drop selected item as list box return null

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, listbox

Im using the following code for drag and drop and the following statement

return null when I checked it in the debug,what is wrong here?

**var mySelectedItem = listbox1.SelectedItem as ListBoxItem;**

```
public MainWindow()
{

    InitializeComponent();
    _UsersList.Add(new User {Name = "Mike"});
    _UsersList.Add(new User { Name = "Nick" });
    listbox1.ItemsSource = _UsersList;

}

public ObservableCollection<User> userList
{
    get { return _UsersList; }
}

private void listbox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.AddedItems.Count > 0 && string.IsNullOrEmpty(textbox1.Text))
    {
        if (listbox1.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
        {
            var mySelectedItem = listbox1.SelectedItem as ListBoxItem;
            if (mySelectedItem != null)
            {
                DragDrop.DoDragDrop(listbox1,  DragDropEffects.Copy);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the xaml is

```
<ListBox x:Name="listbox1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="115" Margin="100,75,0,0" 
                  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="150" ItemsSource="{Binding userList}" 
                  SelectionChanged="listbox1_SelectionChanged" >
```

**UPDATE:**

When I change the lilstBOXItem to **User** or using the following as proposed in the answers im getting different error :

```
 var mySelectedItem = listbox1.ItemContainerGenerator
                        .ContainerFromItem(listbox1.SelectedItem) as ListBoxItem;



private void textbox1_PreviewDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        string name = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.StringFormat).ToString();
        textbox1.Text += name;
        textbox1.Focus();
        textbox1.CaretIndex = textbox1.Text.Length;
        e.Handled = true;
        listbox1.Items.Remove(listbox1.SelectedItem);
    }
```

The error in **listbox1.Items.Remove(listbox1.SelectedItem);**
this statement responsible to remove item that was selected from the list box and dragged to the text box

```
peration is not valid while ItemsSource is in use. Access and modify elements with ItemsControl.ItemsSource instead."}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SelectedItem` will be of type `User`.

If you want to get container i.e. `ListBoxItem` you can get this way:

```
var mySelectedItem = listBox1.ItemContainerGenerator
                        .ContainerFromItem(listBox1.SelectedItem) as ListBoxItem;
```

This will get you actual container which is hosting your object of type User.

---

**UPDATE**

Instead of

```
listbox1.Items.Remove(listbox1.SelectedItem);
```

you should remove from ItemsSource collection and since its `ObservableCollection<User>`, it will update UI automatically.

```
_UsersList.Remove(listBox1.SelectedItem)
```

Comment: i was tried your suggestion but having diffrent error ,please see my update in the post

Comment: You cannot remove from `Items` if have binded `ItemsSource` of listbox.

Comment: Remove the item from ItemsSource collection instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var mySelectedItem = listbox1.SelectedItem as User;
```

Your ItemsSource is a collection of Type User and thus The SelectedItem will be of Type User not of ListBoxItem

Comment: Thanks now its not return null but when I drag and drop I have error in the         private void textbox1_PreviewDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            string name = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.StringFormat).ToString();
            textbox1.Text += name;
            textbox1.Focus();
            textbox1.CaretIndex = textbox1.Text.Length;
            e.Handled = true;
            listbox1.Items.Remove(listbox1.SelectedItem);
        }

Comment: Remove selected item which removing the items from the listBOx ,any idea how to overcome this?

Comment: See Rohit answer for that

Comment: i was tried your suggestion but having different error ,please see my update in the post

Comment: Instead of Remove Set ItemsSource again like listbox1.ItemsSource=listbox1.Items.Where(s=>listbox1.SelectedItem !=s).ToList();

Comment: Tried your suggestion but have error ,doesnt know the Where statement,what should I change here?

Comment: At the Top Write using System.Linq;